# sum up frags and group teams with sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two teams and frag counts

```
| id | teamA_name | teamA_frags | teamB_name | teamB_frags |
| 1  |     5      |     3       |     7      |     9       |
| 2  |     5      |     4       |     7      |     1       |
| 3  |     3      |     2       |     6      |     4       |
| 4  |     3      |     8       |     6      |     8       |
```

Is it possible to sum up all frags and present this data like that?

```
| team | frags |
|  5   |   7   |
|  7   |  10   |
|  3   |  10   |
|  6   |  12   |
```

**EDIT 1**: I tried queries with group by and group concat, but they are not giving me the output I wanted. For example:

```
SELECT teamA_name, teamB_name, SUM(teamA_frags), SUM(teamB_frags) FROM Table;
```

This is summing up frags OK, but printing teams next to eachother. My knowledge of SQL is limited.

Comment: What have you already tried? What should happen when `teamA` == `5` and `teamB` == `3`?

Comment: I tried queries with group by, group concat and sum, but all failed. I have no enough knowledge.

Comment: You should post examples of what you've already tried, and explain why they have failed, also posting any relevant errors, etc.

Comment: Sure, I have just edited my post. WRT "what should happen if teamX = ..." - nothing. It's just a matter of summing up scores and printing these results like I posted in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to unpivot and re-aggregate.  Here is one approach:

```
select team, sum(frags)
from ((select teamA_name as team, teamA_frags as frags
       from t
      ) union all
      (select teamB_name as team, teamB_frags as frags
       from t
      )
     ) t
group by team;
```